# How to pass arguments to aapt when building android apk?

Tags: android, ant, assets, aapt

I'm building an apk using ant on Linux (not using Eclipse), and I'm trying to find an easy way to switch between compressing assets and not, in order to keep my huge database uncompressed for < 2.3.  As per this article:

http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/

I see that it's possible to do this by specifying something like `aapt -0 db`, but I can't find information on how to edit the way ant interacts with aapt.  Or do I have to run aapt by itself?  What do I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Android's build.xml (you'll find this under your SDK, tools and ant) that executes AAPT when building.

Find your build.xml and replace the "-package-resources" target with the target below. I'm pretty sure (not able to test it at the moment) you'd be able to swith compression on and off with either "-Dcompression.disabled=set" when build with ANT or "compression.disabled=set" in your .properties-file.

```
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
    <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
    <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
        <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                command="package"
                versioncode="${version.code}"
                versionname="${version.name}"
                debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                manifest="AndroidManifest.xml"
                assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                androidjar="${android.jar}"
                apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                projectLibrariesResName="project.libraries.res"
                projectLibrariesPackageName="project.libraries.package"
                previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                buildType="${build.target}">
            <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
            <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
            <if>
                <condition>
                    <isset property="compression.disabled" />
                </condition>
                <then>
                    <nocompress/>
                </then>
            </if>
        </aapt>
    </do-only-if-not-library>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank; I didn't end up going this way, since it would have made the apk huge, but glad to know the answer anyway.

Comment: Okay!
You could make it per filetype too by adding an extension-attribute to the nocompress-element.


`<!-- Only .db files -->
    <then>
       <nocompress extension="db"/> 
    </then>`

Comment: Anyone found the way without modyfing android sdk internal files?

Comment: You don't modify Android sdk internal files - instead you add the rules to the build.xml file within your own project

Comment: Thanks Sveinung Kval Bakken for the answer, but this was not quite enough information for those like me who are not familiar with ant.  For others: you want to copy the `<target name="-package-resources"...>...</target>` from android_sdk_dir/tools/ant/build.xml and paste it into the build.xml in your project directory BEFORE `<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />`, then modify the line that says `<nocompress extension="..." />`  See the comment at the end of your project build.xml for guidance.