# Android LatinIME build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to make some changes to LatinIME. I got the code from git repository-

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME

But I don't know how to build the apk file from the code. If anyone has build the LatinIME from the code, can you please share instructions.

Specifically I want to know how to build the dictionary tools (I guess I would need ndk), how to build the native code (again I guess it would required ndk) and finally how to build the java code by using the lib file from native code.

I tried creating Android app project in eclipse (using existing code option) by giving root directory as LatinIME/java I was able to compile but since it didn't have libjni_latinime.so, it crashed. I then got the .so file from emulator and put it in the libs/armeabi-v7a folder. Now I get this exception:

```
10-15 12:54:55.289: E/AndroidRuntime(32253): FATAL EXCEPTION: InitializeBinaryDictionary 
10-15 12:54:55.289: E/AndroidRuntime(32253): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/main_en.dict from drawable resource ID #0x7f070003
```

Comment: I am in the same boat like you! Here's my 2 cents: From what I see, dictionary files, which are under res/raw never get copies over to bin folder, that explains why it can't find dict files at runtime. I'm looking into seeing why that is the case.

Comment: I've compiled latinime.so using android-ndk but now I'm stuck here too

Comment: facing the exactly similar problem, anyone has solution so far?

Answer (score 6):

I think I may have solved this...

Having encountered a similar problem in another project where resources were being unnecessarily compressed due to their file extension I renamed the dictionaries (.dict) to .jet - an extension excluded from compression. Voila, dictionaries are now working. Not sure how good of a resolution that is seeing as the dictionaries are now uncompressed but it's a step in the right direction at least?

Comment: somehow it is working. not sure if there is any side effect.  
anyway, will reward the bounty if no better solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to get the AOSP LatinIME keyboard running too. I've cloned the git repo, even managed to build the libjni_latinime.so file (for all platforms), but now I'm stuck at this. When I rename the dictionaries to .jet I get the error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0, while when I don't rename them I get a (little) different error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/main_en.dict from drawable resource ID #0x7f070003. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to fix it :/

Comment: How does that get around the missing `jni_latinime` library?  The dictionaries are now actually in `.gz` format: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/dictionaries/

Comment: @Toverbal I renamed it to .jet file and then it is working fine. But stuck at generating .so files. Can you please help me ? I will help you with .jet file issue.

Answer (score 6):

So far i have customised the LatinIME many times for different projects. I never faced this problem.
But i never used eclipse to create apks. I downloaded whole AOSP code onto my machine and compiled the modified source with AOSP. And `mm` creates the apk file in out folder, and can be installed with `adb install -r latinime.apk`

Here is how to download AOSP :http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
And here is how to compile it initially : http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html and http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-building-android-from-source

And the LatinIME can be found in `<android roo>/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME`, Modify the code ther and cd to the same path and run `mm` (you need to do `source build/envisetup.sh` and `lunch full-eng` done in same terminal before doing `mm`)

Comment: The size info on aosp site seems outdated. do you know a `lunch full-eng` rehire how many space?

Comment: space on Hard disk drive ?

Comment: yes. Just want to know how much disk space a full-eng requires.

Comment: around 10GB download and after compilation it may grow up to 30GB + 5GB ccache.. Aroung 35GB repo after compilation

Comment: 10G for source download? I did repo sync for the master branch a few times and it ends up with a 30G download for the source. Is there any option to choose the size?

Comment: Nope, probably kitkat repo size increased but its not 30GB i hope.. Try syncing a branch like kitkat/JB.. may receive smaller repo..

Comment: repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1

Comment: Hi Charan. Does this method for customizing the LatinIME still work?

Comment: I am customizing IME for Car but I faced an issue that is supporting only one keyboard is English. I want type Vietnamese but can not. Do you know why? can you give me an advice

Answer (score 5):

First some background. As also suggested by the other answer issue seems to be related of `.dict` files being compressed. For example you can see how official Android builds solve this in [project's tests for LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/tests/Android.mk)

```
# Do not compress dictionary files to mmap dict data runtime
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += -0 .dict
```

A quick searching the web reveals that to day this kind of directive or instructing  aapt from Eclipse isn't trivial. You would probably end up creating a `build.xml` in case you want to handle `don't-compress-dicts` case properly.

One nice suggestion is this [answer/question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392543/1163019) on how to instruct `aapt` to not to compress certain files.

If you want to build this from official git link you provide, you'll end up building whole Android repo, which you can by following [building-running instructions](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html).

Comment: Your `building-running instructions` link doesn't work.

Comment: Your "building-running instructions" link doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

If using gradle, add this

```
android {
 aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'dict'
    }
```