# is it possible to make uncompressed ".so" files on APK?

Tags: android, gradle, aapt, compression

I try to make uncompressed .so apk by added into build.gradle this :

```
aaptOptions { noCompress 'so'}
```

but looks like it doesn't work. The apk still same.

I also tried to change the build.xml inside SDK like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937368/how-to-pass-arguments-to-aapt-when-building-android-apk/8392543#8392543) but the result still same.

So, anyone know how to make it work? is it possible to make uncompressed .so? 
If it possible, is there any obvious different between the compressed and uncompressed? I mean, like files structure inside apk will different maybe.